# How do you access items in an uneditable JComboBox so a method can be run upon selection?

Tags: swing, jython

I know a little Python but unfortunately no Java.  I'm trying to get a minimal Jython example to work, where a method is executed each time an item in my JComboBox is selected.  Instinct tells me I should set an actionPerformed = object for each item, where object is the name of a method I want to run.  I found an example online for JMenuItems, and I got this to work:

```
menubar = swing.JMenuBar()
optionMenu = swing.JMenu('Option')
optionsList = ['First', 'Second', 'Third']
for option in optionsList:
    choice = swing.JMenuItem(option)
    choice.actionPerformed = self.doUponSelection
    optionMenu.add(choice)
menuBar.add(optionMenu)
```

When I tried something similar with swing.JComboBoxItem, it told me no such attribute existed.  Using `dir()` I found javax.swing attributes of JCheckBoxMenuItem, JMenuItem, and JRadioButtonMenuItem.  Does anyone know how I can access the components of a JList or JComboBox?

Note: I have access to Jython 2.5.0

Edit: I've seen the Java documentation (not that I understand the code) that describes explicitly adding an actionListener but did not think that was supposed to be done in Jython.  I know Jython JButtons have an actionPerformed attribute which appears to implement an actionListener and executes actions (combining Java steps).  If it is the JComboBox itself that will fire the event, I'm even more confused because I tried using `myJComboBox.actionPerformed = self.doUponSelection` and it gave me a TypeError saying it was a read only attribute.  It works fine for me with `myJButton.actionPerformed = self.doUponSelection`.

Comment: I don't know about Jython, but for Java swing JComboBox controls, it's the control itself that gets told about changes.  You can add an `ItemListener` to the control. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addItemListener(java.awt.event.ItemListener)

Answer (score 0):

You must add an `ActionListener` to the `JComboBox` itself. When a selection is made, an action event is triggered. In the listener's code, just ask the `JComboBox` for its selected item to know which item is the newly selected one.

Read http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners